# How do I use the Serverless Framework in an Azure DevOps Build Pipeline without Browser Authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy the simple NodeJS hello-world functions the Serverless Framework provides to my Azure free-tier account from an Azure DevOps Build Pipeline using the Service Principal credentials I created when making the deployment from my desktop originally. I've used several of the Build Agents and Tasks combinations, including Windows and Ubuntu Agents as well as Bash, Command Line, Azure Powershell, and Azure CLI tasks with the DevOps provided link to the Service Principal credentials. I've made sure to add them as Pipeline variables so that they are included in the tasks' environmental variables and I've confirmed that they are there when the tasks run. I also make sure that the Azure CLI is installed and logged into with the subscription set. No matter what settings/permissions I tweak or new configurations I try, when the task runs successfully to the point where the serverless framework attempts the deployment it always tries to get me to use a browser to authenticate my account. This obviously defeats the purpose of a CI/CD pipeline and even if I do use a browser to authenticate, the process just hangs there.

The sample code and deployment works on my desktop, so I know the credentials work. I believe I've emulated each step I take on my desktop in the Build Pipeline, yet while my desktop deploys without browser authentication the build always requests it. Does anyone have experience in this manner and know what step/configuration I'm missing?

To look at the sample code and process look [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/examples/hello-world/node/) or run these steps:

1. serverless create -t azure-nodejs -p testApp
2. cd .\testApp\
3. Change Node Runtime and Region in serverless.yml (nodejs12.x not supported & no free tier in West US)
4. serverless deploy

Here's the link I used to get this working on my desktop: [link](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-azure-functions#advanced-authentication)

Edit: Here is the default serverless.yml created by the steps above:

```
service: azure-serverless-helloworld

provider:
  name: azure
  region: East US
  runtime: nodejs8.10

  environment:
    VARIABLE_FOO: 'foo'

plugins:
  - serverless-azure-functions

package:
  exclude:
    - local.settings.json
    - .vscode/**
    - index.html

functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/handlers/hello.sayHello
    events:
      - http: true
        x-azure-settings:
          methods:
            - GET
          authLevel: anonymous

  goodbye:
    handler: src/handlers/goodbye.sayGoodbye
    events:
      - http: true
        x-azure-settings:
          methods:
            - GET
          authLevel: anonymous
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below steps to run `sls package` in `command line task` to create a deployment package, and then use `Azure Function App` task to deploy to azure.

> 1,install specific version nodejs using **Node.js tool installer** task

_

> 2, install serverless using **npm task** to run custom command

[image]

> 3, use **npm task** to run install command to install dependencies

_

> 4, Use **command line** task to run `sls package` to create the deployment package

[image]
[image]

_

> 5, use azure function app deploy task to deploy the deployment package

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work/help. I made some attempts at this method today with no success. It would "deploy" the created package/zip file but when I'd go to make API calls they wouldn't work properly and when I looked at the App/Function through the Azure portal there is nothing there. I guess we're going to have to ditch the Serverless Framework for our new Azure environments as nothing works the same as it does in AWS. Thanks for the effort though, it's truly appreciated.

Comment: This approach seems to work for me albeit after some problems. However, it does not quite help when trying to deploy a new function together.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the Serverless Framework thinks you're trying to deploy your application using the Serverless Dashboard (which does not yet support Azure).

I'm not sure, because it haven't posted your `serverless.yml` file, but I think you'll need to remove the `app` and `org` attributes from your `serverless.yml` configuration file. Then it will stop asking you to log in.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited the question to include the serverless.yml created by the serverless command I originally posted:


`serverless create -t azure-nodejs -p testApp`


I've excluded their comments for readability. I don't see any org or app attributes in this file. The above command should generate any relevant code/configuration files as I'm trying to keep it simple before making any personal modifications.

Comment: Oh! I suppose I didn't understand from your post - where are you being asked to sign in? Is it Azure? Or Serverless.com?

Comment: The serverless framework is asking me to take an Azure CLI token and put it into [https://aka.ms/devicelogin](https://aka.ms/devicelogin) so that it can validate my Azure account and make deployments there on my behalf.

Comment: @MitchellEtzel Have you managed to find a way to solve this in the end? Facing exactly the same issue as you were, and I can't find some good documentation explaining these sorts of authentication automation processes

Answer (score 0):

Using the serverless framework to deploy a function through DevOps gave me the same issue.
The problem is that the sls deplopy command will build, package and deploy the code but will ask you for credentials each time you run the pipeline.

I solved this using the command serverless package in the build task, after that I deployed the zip that was generated for the command with a normal web app deploy task.